# Table view cells unwanted excess separator lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Ok this might be a very simple answer but I'm still pretty fresh when it comes to iOS development. I'm creating a simple app just to play with different concepts and the problem I am having with my TableViewController is the excess lines. To be clear I will post a picture and circle what I am talking about, and my question is how do I make it to where the only lines showing are the ones where cells are actually populated so in my case the first 3 cells and I circled the unwanted lines.
[image]

Comment: just add Tablefooterview.like "Table.tableFooterView = [UIView new];"

Comment: This is the cutest question I've seen on this site :-)

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati would I put that in View did load?? If not where else?

Comment: viewWillAppear is better place for this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add These codes to your .m file:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView  =[[UIView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectZero];  //set your tableView's tableFooterView
}
```

Comment: This was the fix thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. there is so many answer there on stackOverflow for this. just add Footerview to your tableview.add following code in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UITableView *tableView; //this is your tableview
    tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
}
```

Comment: If I sound stupid I'm sorry but there is no viewWillAppear in my code, i even used the finder to search for it, i tried this code in viewdidload and it didn't work. There is no way to do it in Storyboard?

Comment: just look at my edit

Comment: @IanKunneke You need to add the viewWillAppear method yourself, it is not already there.

Comment: In the future, if you know the question is a duplicate, flag the question as a duplicate instead of posting yet another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to drag a UIView into the TableView in InterfaceBuilder , then set the UIView instance height to 1px and it's background color to [UIColor clearColor].

And if you don't use InterfaceBuilder , you can make the same UIView instance in your code and set the instance to tableview.tableFooterView.